# Would it be possible to alter the chemical composition of a planet’s atmosphere for humans?

Tags: science-fiction, atmosphere, terraforming

If my civilization (composed of humans who have extremely advanced technology such as portal engines (which can create traversable wormholes from one end) is terraforming worlds and creating colonies across the galaxy, then they may have to alter the chemical composition of atmospheres of the planets they’re wanting to colonize to make those atmospheres breathable.  Would this be possible in the very distant future assuming real world science?

If there are limitations for the kinds of atmospheres that could be modified (such as the original composition of the atmosphere), then feel free to add that as a limitation of the method used in your answer.

Comment: I think a lot depends on what the starting composition of the atmosphere is, if it's like Mars or early Earth, sure, if it's more like Venus, probably not. :)

Comment: You have not tagged this question with a science-hardness tag - which is good, because trying to give all the possible change techniques for all the possible atmospheres would require a (multi-)book-length answer, which would be a VTC.  So do not expect a more detailed answer than that you have received from L.Dutch without being more specific - especially since you have not even specified whether your civilization is human or some other life form!

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Thank you for the recommendation, I just clarified.

Comment: (a) `Would this be possible in the very distant future assuming real world science?` The answer to that question is always "probably yes." It fails to meet Stack Exchange's standards for questions being specific and about solvable problems. (b) VTC:Needs More Focus because I can't tell how many questions you're asking. Certainly more than one. "Feel free to add..." sounds innocuous, but "of the technology in your answer" is not the question you asked in the title of the question or the first paragraph.

Comment: BTW, you have a habit of asking, "can this be done?" If you think about it, that's a useless question. It's your world, by definition it can be done if only *by declaration.* A far more valuable question is, "I want to do X, but I'm stuck developing the solution at Y, what can I do to overcome Y?" This Stack is incredibly good at that kind of question.

Comment: @JBH I can try to start rephrasing questions to not say “can this be done”, but generally when I’m using that phrasing, it’s because I’m asking if real world science would make it impossible or vice versa.  I’ve also seen plenty of other people here using that phrasing as well.

Comment: @KalMadda That's not what I've read from any of your questions - and by definition, *everything you've asked* cannot be done with present-day real-world science and any limitation of science known today is not and cannot be guaranteed to be a limitation in the distant future you're asking about. Note that whether or not other questions are worded that way is irrelevant and does not set a precedent. It may not seem like it, but I'm actually trying to help you ask more constructive and more valuable questions. So far, you've not wanted to listen.

Comment: @JBH Like I said, I can try to remember to rephrase my questions like you suggested.  I have no problem following your advice, just explaining why the answer to my questions can’t necessarily be an automatic yes.

Comment: If I understand your second sentence, the answer is an automatic yes because 99.9% of all human technology was invented in the last 150 years. The technology to create artificial wormholes might be in the 150-years-from-now range. But whether it is or not, it's far enough out that Clarkean Magic is involved. The moment Clarkean Magic enters the picture, the answer to "is this possible" is always "yes." Magic overcomes everything. It's important (especially here) to be specific about the problem you're trying to solve. In a real sense, what's stopping you from saying "yes" and moving forward?

Comment: You can't edit the question in ways that invalidate the existing answers. Since your edit did that, I have rolled it back.

Comment: @L.Dutch Ok, sorry about that, I was just trying to edit things to clarify it a bit.  Are there any edits you’d recommend I make to fix the issues with the question so it could be reopened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the very concept of terraforming.

And changing the composition of the atmosphere is something we are doing already now on our own planet. Just to cite a few examples:

- the [level of CO2 in the atmosphere](https://earth.org/data_visualization/a-brief-history-of-co2/) has been increased by human activities

[image]

- we have increased the [content of $C^{14}$ in the atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bomb_pulse) thanks to all the nuclear tests in the second half of the past century

[image]

- we have added gases in the atmosphere that depleted the ozone layer

Comment: So would this be able to be done in a useful way that would change an atmosphere from non-livable to breathable?